# How do I correct this in a correct way? "I do not want to interfere with my work due to my personal schedule

Tags: grammaticality

As you guessed the meaning, there are situations where I need to deal with my personal things, but I do not want to let the company know or interrupt my work. I want to separate my personal things and work at the company.

How do I say correctly?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be ELL related, but  rather a matter for [workplace.se] or [interpersonal.se]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure which way round you mean, here are some possibilities:

If you mean that you dont want your personal schedule to interfere with work: "I do not intend for my personal schedule to interfere with my work"

If you mean that your work should not interfere in your personal life: "I would prefer that my work not interfere with my personal schedule/time" (using the subjunctive)